# Iterate requests to a list and append the results into one variable

Tags: python, api, python-requests

I use Requests for storing the result of an API call into a variable. 
It works fine for one single url but I cant iterate the requests on the a list of items with different parameters.
Each API result is a csv file. Once the request is done for each element of the list how can I append the different files togheter?

Here what I have:

```
import requests
import pandas as pd
from StringIO import StringIO

applicata = requests.session()

try:
results = applicata.get('https://api.php?', 
                    auth=('xxx',
                          'xxx'), 
                    verify=False)
except:
    print('no authentication.')
```

But I want to iterate the get request over the variable "link" - and append the three results one below the other:

```
def calls(x): 
    return 'https://api.php?&page=' + x
pages = ["1","2","3"]
links = map(link, pages)
```

Any hint?

Comment: Does this question have anything to do with `requests`?  Or are you just trying to find out how to concatenate .csv files?

Comment: I would like to understand how to iterate the .get() method on different pages (with different parameters). @BrendanAbel

Comment: Why can't you just loop through the urls and call .get() on each of them?